# Dynamic form fields not going into rows

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

I have a dynamic formGroup modal and i wanted to assign form-fields into rows.

```
        <div *ngFor="let header of headers">
            <!--row 1-->
            <div class="container" style="background-color:yellow">
                <div class="row" *ngIf="header.options['row'] == '1'">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Enter {{header.columnName}}"
                                formControlName={{header.columnID}} />
                            <mat-error>{{header.columnName}} is
                                <strong>required</strong>
                            </mat-error>
                            <mat-hint align="start">Please enter
                                <strong>{{header.columnName}}</strong>
                            </mat-hint>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--row 2-->
            <div class="container" style="background-color:red">
                <div class="row" *ngIf="header.options['row'] == '2'">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <input matInput placeholder="Enter {{header.columnName}}"
                                formControlName={{header.columnID}} />
                            <mat-error>{{header.columnName}} is
                                <strong>required</strong>
                            </mat-error>
                            <mat-hint align="start">Please enter
                                <strong>{{header.columnName}}</strong>
                            </mat-hint>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

header data

```
  [
    { columnID: 'id', columnName: 'Id', type: 'number', options: { alignment: '', color: '', row: '1' } },
    { columnID: 'make', columnName: 'Make', type: 'string', options: { alignment: '', color: '', row: '1' } },
    { columnID: 'model', columnName: 'Model', type: 'string', options: { alignment: '', color: '', row: '2' } },
    { columnID: 'fuelType', columnName: 'Fuel Type', type: 'string', options: { alignment: '', color: '', row: '2' } },
    { columnID: 'isActive', columnName: 'Is Active?', type: 'bool', options: { alignment: '', color: '', row: '2' } }
];
```

modal output. as you can see on the datasource 'id' and 'make' should be on row 1 and the others on row 2. but instead they are all vertical.
Any help would be appreciated. thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Try this

```
    <div>
        <!--row 1-->
        <div class="container" style="background-color:yellow">
            <div class="row">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let header of headers">
                <div class="col-sm" *ngIf="header.options['row'] == '1'">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput placeholder="Enter {{header.columnName}}"
                            formControlName={{header.columnID}} />
                        <mat-error>{{header.columnName}} is
                            <strong>required</strong>
                        </mat-error>
                        <mat-hint align="start">Please enter
                            <strong>{{header.columnName}}</strong>
                        </mat-hint>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--row 2-->
        <div class="container" style="background-color:red">
            <div class="row">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let header of headers">
                <div class="col-sm" *ngIf="header.options['row'] == '2'">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput placeholder="Enter {{header.columnName}}"
                            formControlName={{header.columnID}} />
                        <mat-error>{{header.columnName}} is
                            <strong>required</strong>
                        </mat-error>
                        <mat-hint align="start">Please enter
                            <strong>{{header.columnName}}</strong>
                        </mat-hint>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This should work. However, if the data structure could have been made as a tree, would have been easier to implement in HTML.

Hope it helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Ok. wait a few minutes,.. Will give you the solution

Comment: Thanks. Though it is really late here now. I cant promise to be awake later

Comment: I have edited the answer, if you could check and let me know if it works

Comment: That worked. can you explain how it worked and what do you mean by tree data struc? Thanks!

Comment: `*ngFor` repeats the components. So, the entire structure was being repeated with each field coming in a separate container. I created 2 `ngFor` loops for the 2 rows and using `*ngIf` restricted the content for each row.

Comment: If we could restructure the header data to contain an array of rows and each row containing an array of columns, we can have a much simpler and better implementation